# Spring MVC controller to return view or JSON

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible for a method in Spring Controller to be able to return either a JSON or a view based on some conditions?

Can someone please share examples.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: You should make an attempt yourself to solve the problem and share your findings here. For starters look into `ViewResolvers`. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution among others : you can use two methods in your `Controller`, one using the `@ResponseBody` annotation and returning a JSON value and one classical method returning a `ModelAndView`.

Both methods could use the same http endpoint with different parameters (query or header parameters). In my point of view, the cleaner way to route the request to the expected format is using `Content-Type` header with the following values : `text/html` and `application/json` (or a path extension `.html` or `.json` but I'd prefer the header solution).

To do that you can use the `consumes` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

An even better design would be to separate your methods that return JSON in `@RestController` annoted classes with real restfull endpoints and your your classical MVC's methods with non-restfull endpoints (generally bad for the SEO) in `@Controller` annoted classes that are only reserved for MVC (and both controller's families can use the same business logic in `@Service` annoted classes that not expose http endpoints).

If you really want to use a single method and determine with some conditions the format of your output, I think that would be a really bad design for your http clients but it's still possible using [`ViewResolvers`](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial) like [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149440/bart) suggests in comments.